# "Spring Extension" search does not show Gradle in list in STS-3.8.3

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I want to start a spring boot project using gradle in STS-3.8.3. But I am not being able to select build type "Gradle STS". It says I need to install gradle from Dashboard extension.

[image]

But When I open the dashboard extension, It does not show gradle in searching list.

[image]

Someone please let me know why it is not present in the list and how can I make this available in the list.

Thanks.

Comment: The extension install page was empty due to a temporary outage. It should be back by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to install gradle (STS) from eclipse market place since "Spring Tool Suite" has planed to completely remove support for it. They now recommend to use "Gradle Buildship" which can be found in Eclipse market place.
Details could be found here: http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v372/NewAndNoteworthy.html